# Eclipse Start Error in Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse

In my work space, when I want to start the eclipse, the following error occurs...I am using linux. What's the issue?

```
(Eclipse:9665): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_context_set_language: assertion `context != NULL' failed

 (Eclipse:9665): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_new: assertion `context != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_text: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_attributes: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_alignment: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_ellipsize: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_single_paragraph_mode: assertion `PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_set_width: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion `layout != NULL' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_size_lookup_for_settings: assertion `GTK_IS_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(Eclipse:9665): Gtk-WARNING **: Invalid icon size 6


(Eclipse:9665): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_load_icon: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: What version of eclipse your trying to launch ? 
What is your distribution ? 
Do you have all the dependencies with the correct versions installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question is lacking, some key information. I would suggest you to go over following steps

1. Check the version of eclipse you are trying to run if it is compatible with your distribution version
2. Check if all dependencies are installed on your distro, e.g. (check the pango lib version)
3. etc.

Need more help, then provide more info !